# Not getting unique results with WHERE IN but GROUP BY is to slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I am trying to get the unique results tables with many to many relationship. I have tables with videos, table with categories and pivot table. When i want to select only videos that belong to one category. I have approximately 50.000 videos and about 90 categories. When i tried next query i am getting duplicate of videos (one for every category), and i want only unique videos to show up.

```
SELECT video_id, add_date  FROM videos 
INNER JOIN video_category ON videos.id = video_category.video_id
WHERE video_id IN (2, 1, 3, ... , 60) 
ORDER BY add_date DESC, video_id DESC
```

When i tried grouping by video_id:

```
SELECT video_id, add_date  FROM videos 
INNER JOIN video_category ON videos.id = video_category.video_id
WHERE video_id IN (2, 1, 3, ... , 60) 
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY add_date DESC, video_id DESC
```

this query took about 5-7 seconds which is too long.

Any suggestions how can i rewrite this?

EDIT:
Added table aliases

Comment: do you have create statements for the tables you use and an execution plan for those queries?

Comment: Please edit your question to include table aliases for the columns.  It is hard to make suggestions without knowing where the columns come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that this is your query:

```
SELECT s.video_id, s.add_date
FROM ac_scene s INNER JOIN
     ac_scene_category sc
     ON s.id = sc.ac_scene_id 
WHERE sc.ac_category_id IN (2, 1, 3, ... , 60) 
GROUP BY s.video_id
ORDER BY s.add_date DESC, s.video_id DESC;
```

If so, consider rewriting the query and adding appropriate indexes:

```
select s.video_id, s.add_date
from ac_scene s
where exists (select 1
              from ac_scene_category sc
              where s.id = sc.ac_scene_id and
                    sc.ac_category_id IN (2, 1, 3, ... , 60)
             )
order by s.add_date DESC, s.video_id DESC;
```

For best performance, create an index on `ac_scene_category(ac_scene_id, ac_category_id)` and on `ac_scene(s.add_date, s.video_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant really simplify your query any more. If 5-7 seconds is too long then then the performance problem will be with your database and not your query.

However try using DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT video_id, add_date  FROM ac_scene 
INNER JOIN ac_scene_category ON ac_scene.id = ac_scene_category.ac_scene_id 
WHERE ac_category_id IN (2, 1, 3, ... , 60) 
ORDER BY add_date, video_id DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't make much of a difference :/

Comment: DISTINCT will return to you unique results of video_id and add_date. What more do you want?

Comment: Yes but it takes takes too much tim... i will probably have to consider reorganizig this bit of database :S
PS thanks for your help